# Installing superset I am getting this 'error no support for running processes with linux/amd64/v8 platform, supported: linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2'

Tags: installation, arm64, apache-superset

I wanted to run Apache superset in my Mac M2 by Docker compose. But it is constantly giving me error.

```
 % docker compose up
WARN[0000] The "CYPRESS_CONFIG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
WARN[0000] The "CYPRESS_CONFIG" variable is not set. Defaulting to a blank string. 
[+] Running 1/1
 ! superset-websocket Warning                                                                                                                                                                              4.4s 
[+] Building 2.2s (9/12)                                                                                                                                                                   docker:desktop-linux
 => [superset-websocket internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.20kB                                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
 => [superset-websocket internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 842B                                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [superset-websocket internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:16-alpine                                                                                                                       2.2s
 => [superset-websocket auth] library/node:pull token for registry-1.docker.io                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => [superset-websocket internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => transferring context: 1.80kB                                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [superset-websocket stage-1 1/5] FROM docker.io/library/node:16-alpine@sha256:a1f9d027912b58a7c75be7716c97cfbc6d3099f3a97ed84aa490be9dee20e787                                                         0.0s
 => CACHED [superset-websocket stage-1 2/5] WORKDIR /home/superset-websocket                                                                                                                               0.0s
 => CACHED [superset-websocket build 3/4] COPY . ./                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => ERROR [superset-websocket build 4/4] RUN npm ci &&   npm run build                                                                                                                                     0.0s
------
 > [superset-websocket build 4/4] RUN npm ci &&   npm run build:
------
failed to solve: no support for running processes with linux/amd64/v8 platform, supported: linux/amd64, linux/amd64/v2
```

I ran this command as well but it has not solved my issue.

```
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=linux/x86_64/v8
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to build superset by updating the docker compose:

```
    platform: linux/amd64/v8
...
superset-websocket:
    platform: linux/amd64
...
superset-init:
    platform: linux/amd64/v8
...
superset-node:
    platform: linux/amd64/v8
...
 superset-worker:
    platform: linux/amd64/v8
...
 superset-worker-beat:
    platform: linux/amd64/v8
...
superset-tests-worker:
    platform: linux/amd64/v8
```

The fix was mentioned here: https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/25434. Later you have to clear the var you set and build from scrach:

```
export DOCKER_DEFAULT_PLATFORM=
docker-compose build --no-cache
```